# Prevent .csproj files from being locked in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We currently have TFS locked to prevent people from modifying the same file, however there are a few files that are getting annoying because they are constantly being modified like (.csproj, .config), we have to include these in source control but we also have to keep our locks on since we have so many people working on the same branch, and we had nothing but issues with everyone on different branches.

Currently we just either wait till someone checks it in, or having them check in early, which is being a pain.

Any way to exclude the project files from being locked?

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution from a "best practices" perspective is to **enable multiple check-out**. If letting multiple people work on the same file at the same time is causing pain, you have a cultural problem that needs to be solved, not a tools problem.